# Sesión perdida al recargar página

Tags: php, apache, session, slim, vagrant

Tras logear, guardo en `$_SESSION['user']` el nombre de usuario y redirijo a `/dashboard/index.php`. Después hago click en un link de mi menú para redirigirme, por ejemplo a la url `/dashboard/kanboard/index.php` donde la variable de sesión que cité antes sigue ahí y hace correctamente las comprobaciones necesarias. El problema está en que si desde esta página hago click en F5 o en cualquier otro link, al intentar comprobar si la variable de sesión existe, no la encuentra y me devuelve al login. Todo este comportamiento es bastante extraño ya que si refresco directamente en el primer index (`/dashboard/index.php`) las veces que haga falta, la variable se conserva correctamente.

Ante todo y antes de que se critique la calidad y limpieza del código, he de decir que todo lo que muestre es código de prueba.

Este problema surgió al migrar el proyecto de un contenedor docker con Debian, Apache y PHP 7.3.1 a una máquina Vagrant con Centos 7, Apache, y PHP 7.3.3 por lo que puede que el problema principal no esté en el código si no en la configuración de Apache o de PHP. Además, antes todas las carpetas del proyecto estaban tiradas en /www/html y ahora están en /www/html/dashboard, que tampoco se si tendrá algo que ver.

De todas formas, dejo parte del código de ambas páginas por si fuese problema del mismo, si no ¿que puede estar faltándome en la configuración del servidor o de PHP?

**dashboard/index.php**

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$titulo = "Index";
include $path.'/dashboard/includes/userData.php';
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
   <?php
    include $path.'/dashboard/includes/header.php';
    ?>
  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
            <!-- sidebar menu -->
            <?php
            include $path.'/dashboard/includes/menu.php';
            include $path.'/dashboard/includes/top-bar.php';
            ?>
        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">

        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->

        <?php
            include $path.'/dashboard/includes/footer.php';
        ?>  
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var index = new Index(JSON.parse('<?php echo getJSONUser()?>'));
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**dashboard/kanboard/index.php**

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$migas = "../";
$titulo = "Resumen Imputaciones";
include $path . '/dashboard/includes/userData.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <?php
    include $path . '/dashboard/includes/header.php';
    ?>
    <!-- MONGO Chart-->
    <script src="/dashboard/vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="nav-md">

<!-- MODAL INFORMACION DETALLADA -->
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalinfo">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="mtitulo"></h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float: right;">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="mbody">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- FIN MODAL INFORMACION DETALLADA -->

<div class="container body">
    <div class="main_container">
        <!-- sidebar menu -->
        <?php
        include $path . '/dashboard/includes/menu.php';
        include $path . '/dashboard/includes/top-bar.php';
        ?>
        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">
            <div class="">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="x_panel form-panel">
                            <div class="x_title">
                                <h2>Resumen Imputaciones</h2>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="x_content">
                                <?php
                                if (isAdministrator()) {
                                    ?>
                                    <div id="tableImputaciones-loader" class="div-loader">
                                        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse spinner"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row" id="imputaciones">
                                        <div id="tablaImputacionesContainer"
                                             class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <table id="tableImputaciones" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                                                   style="width:100%">
                                                <thead id="tableImputacionesHead">
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody id="tableImputacionesBody">
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 more-results">
                                            <button type="button" title="Mostrar más"
                                                    class="btn btn-lg button-more-results" data-total-paginas="1"
                                                    data-tabla-ref="tableImputaciones"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"
                                                                                          aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="hidden" id="last-index"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        include $path . '/dashboard/includes/modals/showUrl.php';
        include $path . '/dashboard/includes/footer.php';
        ?>
        <!-- ECharts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/vendors/echarts/dist/echarts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/kanboard/js/utils.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/kanboard/js/index.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var index = new Index('<?php echo getUserName()?>');
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Método que comprueba si el usuario está logeado**

```
function userIsAuth()
{
    // Si no hay una sesión iniciada, lo hacemos
    if (! isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    // If existe la variable de sesión "user" entonces es que un usuario ha iniciado sesión
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** La llamada a la función userIsAuth está incluida en /dashboard/includes/userData.php la cual está incluida en todos los documentos. Dicha función llama a session_start();

**Edit 2:** Agrego una imagen de la configuración de sesión que saca phpinfo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edit 3:** He hecho algunos cambios en el `php.ini` para tratar de igualarlo lo más posible al entorno original donde está el proyecto (salvando ciertas diferencias por el tipo de entorno y el propio SO). Además ahora he agregado en la primera línea de cada página el `session_start()` y eliminado dicha instrucción de `userData`. Con ello, ha dejado de cargar cualquier variable guardada en `$_SESSION` previamente y además se han mostrado 2 nuevos warnings.

[image: Primer warning]
[image: Segundo warning]

Tambien, he probado a cambiar en el `php.ini` la propiedad `session.auto_start` de `Off` a `On` y eliminando todos los `session_start` pero todo ello me llevo a distintos errores con la API que estoy utilizando para recuperar ciertos datos (la api utiliza Slim Framework y carga también un `session_start`).

**Edit 4:** He conseguido que no aparezcan los warnings tocando el valor de `output_buffering` del `php.ini`, estaba en 0 y ahora lo he puesto en 4096 (parece ser el valor recomendado). Ahora me encuentro con que los valores que guardo dentro de `$_SESSION` al loguear no están. Curipsamente, si justo después del `session_start();` meto un `var_dump($_SESSION)` estos valores si aparecen y los errores dejan de aparecer.

Curiosamente, he descubierto otro comportamiento. Tras loguear puede aparecer el comportamiento que he descrito en Edit 4 o puede soltar el primer error mostrado en el Edit 3 y mostrar los datos de `$_SESSION` correctamente.

Comment: Pero, si esa función es llamada en todos los archivos ¿no es lo mismo? a efectos, se está ejecutando cada vez que carga una página, la diferencia es que en lugar de repetir código, simplemente se llama a la función correspondiente.

Comment: ``$migas`` es código obsoleto, antes las rutas eran relativas y por eso está ahí pero no se está utilizando (si te fijas ahora se hace referencia a ``$path`` que contiene el documentroot con lo que siempre parte del mismo sitio. He probado el require y no hay cambio, tampoco suelta ningún error incluyendo en los 3 archivos (login, /index y /kanboard/index )     ``<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>`` y no muestra nada

Comment: Acabo de volver a probar por si acaso y el resultado es el mismo, como digo, userIsAuth se ejecuta siempre que se carga la página y si la sesión no existe, la inicia.

Comment: Si, he probado sin el condicional iniciando la sessión en la primera línea (tras abrir las etiquetas php por supuesto), en cuanto al ``var_dump`` en ``/index.php`` me muestra la variable de sesión correctamente, en ``/kanboard/index.php`` también, pero cuando recargo en esta última me muestra ``array (size=0)
  empty`` todo ello con el session_start como me habéis indicado. En cuanto a la configuración del ``php.ini`` ¿que es lo que tengo que tocar exactamente?

Comment: He agregado una imagen con la información que muestra phpinfo por si puede ayudar

Comment: @BlackSheep he agregado más información, a ver si conseguimos encontrar alguna solución :)

Comment: He conseguido que no aparezcan los warnings tocando el valor de ``output_buffering`` del ``php.ini``, estaba en 0 y ahora lo he puesto en 4096 (parece ser el valor recomendado). Ahora me encuentro con que los valores que guardo dentro de ``$_SESSION`` al loguear no están. Curipsamente, si justo después del ``session_start();`` meto un ``var_dump($_SESSION)`` estos valores si aparecen y los errores dejan de aparecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras muchos días de ver por que podía estar fallando todo este asunto, al final se ha solucionado poniendo rutas relativas en el menú.

En los ejemplos que expuse, uno de los includes era el siguiente:

```
include $path.'/dashboard/includes/menu.php';
```

El cual tenía el siguiente trozo de código

```
<ul class="nav child_menu">
    <?php
        if (isAdministrator()) {
    ?>
            <li><a href="/dashboard/kanboard/index.php">Resumen</a></li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>                         
</ul>
```

Si lo sustituyo por el siguiente:

```
<ul class="nav child_menu">
    <?php
        if (isAdministrator()) {
            echo  '<li><a href="'.$migas.'kanboard/index.php">Resumen</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

La sesión se mantiene correctamente.